Exercise (electric field in a dielectric)
I am trying to solve the following exercise about the electric field generated by a spherical conductor:

"A spherical conductor of ray $R=8cm$ and charged with $Q=8\mu C$ is half contained in a liquid of dielectric constant $\varepsilon_r=3$, while the other half is in the air. In conditions of electrostatic equilibrium, determine the electric field $E$ at a distance $r>R$ from the centre of the sphere".

What I know is that, since the sphere is a conductor, the direction of the electric field is radial. My question is: How can I calculate its intensity? I cannot calculate it as the sum of the intensities of the electric fields generated by the two hemispheres, because the first one is in a dielectric material, while the second one is in the air. May I have to use somehow the vector $D$ of electric displacement?

Ask yourself, what does the change in epsilon actually do to the field? And  can you make the problem simpler in some way? Could you break the problem up into components?
